# removeAttribute do not return true or false

Tags: javascript

I am trying  to remove attributes of a  DOM element using below statement in javascript.

```
var res = nodes.removeAttribute("style");
```

but the res is always "undefined" it seems that the  removeAttribute function does not return anything (I tested it on firefox browser)

How can I identify that the attribute is successfully removed or not ?

Thanks,
Sourabh

Comment: http://www.w3.org/TR/REC-DOM-Level-1/level-one-core.html#method-removeAttribute — “This method returns nothing.”

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`nodes`? It seems that you have an array of `node`s. Anyway, `removeAttribute` will not return anything. To check if the attribute has been removed, use `hasAttribute` afterwards.

```
node.removeAttribute('foo');
if (node.hasAttribute('foo')) {
  // failed, foo still exists.
}
```

Answer (score 0):

nodes.removeAttribute("style");

var isTheLanguageWorkingLikeItShouldAndThisCheckIsTotallyPointless = nodes.getAttribute("style");

Comment: What if I dont know if the style attr already exist before I remove it?

Comment: Then do the "get" before "remove".

Comment: ohh that will be too much...but seems that its the only way to do it.